# Obtengo el error "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'"

Tags: python, base-de-datos, excel, pandas, funciones

Tengo el problema al intentar modelar unos datos

"modelo_regresion.fit(X_train, y_train)"

Al intentar ejecutarla Obtengo este error:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiF5a.pngTypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: Deberias aportar un script que podamos ejecutar y reproduzca el error, o almenos la información de la base de datos de la que salen las muestras para el modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que X_train o y_train son del tipo datetime. Has lo siguiente antes de la línea `modelo_regresion.fit(X_train, y_train)` coloca

```py
print(f'Tipo X_train: {type(X_train)} Tipo y_train: {type(y_train)}')
```

Esta line va imprimir que tipo de datos son los dos valores, si alguno de ellos es datatime, ese es el error, debes convertirlo a  `string` antes de pasarlo a la función `fit()`.

Sin ver el código que tienes antes de llamar la función  `fit()`, es un poco difícil darte una solución más precisa.

si tienes el jupyter notebook o el google colab puedes compartirlo así la comunidad te podrá dar más información.

Lo que está pasando es que en algún punto estas pasando datos que son del tipo datetime por lo que algo dentro de la función `fit()` falla, ya que está esperando un `string` o un `int` para convertirlo en un `float`.